# Creating custom sprites

Tags: android, animation, graphics

I want to create my own sprite sheet from a single image i have by modifying the image(like changing the position of the leg).For example lets say i have an image of a man running.I want to create a sprite sheet from this single image.What software do i use for this.From want i understand texturepacker and other such softwares enable you to edit the spritesheet.But as of now i have no images in the sprite sheet except for one.
        Another question i had was that lets say i want to create my own sprites,how do i do this.(Are there softwares available for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simple program to create spritesheets from swf animation, [SWFSheet](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2939), written by Keith Peters. Animation can be created in Flash or any 2d animation editor which supports export to swf like KToon, SWF Quicker, Giotto and so on.

And maybe single-framed bitmap can be animated using morphing?

Comment: Thanks a lot.Will try out the link you have given me.

Comment: Just another question.What are the good flash creators available for free.